# Running two PostgreSQL servers in same Ubuntu machine

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

Please let us know  in an Ubuntu 14.04 Machine is it possible to run same PostgreSQL 9.4 Instances in same machine with different ports.

We installed PostgreSQL 9.4 in two Ubuntu servers and now we need to configure Slave servers for these two servers. So in a third Ubuntu server we installed PostgreSQL 9.4 running on port 5432 and configured as slave server.

Now is it possible to install PostgreSQL 9.4 server on this server that runs on port 5433 so that we can configure second slave server on this machine itself.

Can anyone please help us on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Please let us know in an Ubuntu 14.04 Machine is it possible to run same PostgreSQL 9.4 Instances in same machine with different ports.

Yes, that's why Ubuntu has `pg_wrapper`.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL and the manual for [`pg_createcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html), `pg_ctlcluster`, etc.

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a wrapper for `pg_basebackup`. So you'll need to take a base backup manually if you want to run a replica. You can `pg_createcluster`, stop it, delete the data directory, and replace it with a base backup.